# Adding Cordova plugin into Netbeans?

Tags: cordova, netbeans, plugins, orientation

**EDIT :**

I have tried adding this into the cordova plugins file:

```
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation=https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation.git
```

and I call it in JS like

**JS :**

```
if ($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id') === "home") {

                    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');           
            }
```

so if page1 is the active page, it should lock in landscape.

I am trying to add a Cordova plugin into Netbeans. I am creating a Hybrid mobile application and I need this plugin: https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

I have done a lot of research but I am having no luck. Please help me.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? What stops you from adding this plugin? Please add more info, some code snippets (if you can), and a place where you are stuck. It would help people help you ;)

Comment: @Roman I simply just don't know how lol. I've never added a plugin and this seems to be a third party plugin so I am even more confused.

Comment: @Roman I have added some code to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

If u are using netbean ide to develop ur app

Follow this step to add ur plugin.

if you open project properties (right click on your project->properties) and select Cordova->Plugins, there is a note that you can edit [projectFolder]/nbproject/plugins.properties file to manually add plugins. Add following line for InAppBrowser

org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

and build your project.

Hope it solve ur problem. I a also having problem to make this inappbrowser latest version i installed work with cordova 5.4.1

If yours work let me know and guide me on ow to go about it